# How to extract at text from an image with horizontal line using Tesseract OCR?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

[image: OCR image]

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

value=Image.open("v.jpg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(value, lang="eng")    
print(text)
```

But i don't get any output from OCR

Comment: Anyone would like to help me?

Comment: quality is too low for getting output using Tesseract. You can try using Microsoft Azure text extraction.

Answer (score 0):

Convert this image into gray scale and blur it using Gaussian blurring technique (opencv) , and then try to find countours in it , draw bounding box around it and try to extract those area , and then apply tesseract
This methodology will surely work